# Replace a red Led activation on RPI 4

Tags: pi-4, led

I have a PI 4 and accidentally broke the red led. I don know how to identify it in order to get a replace piece and soldering Any idea or help, please?

Comment: I think the gear you would need to do that soldering job will 1) Cost you much more than the replacement cost of the Pi, 2) Include a learning curve such that your first repair will fail in a bad way, destroying the rest of the board.  But I'll leave it up to the more experienced to confirm or deny that...

Comment: @goldilocks: Both good points. Personally, I find the RED LED (Power LED) obnoxious and redundant. I actually spent some time figuring out how to disable mine, and use the Activity (Green) LED to serve both functions: Activity and Power.

Comment: This is just an 0603 package LED, so it's pretty easily replaced using a regular soldering iron (which I assume Luis has, otherwise yeah the cost wouldn't be worth it). Does depend on how much soldering experience Luis has though.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are referring to the PWR led on the board. Just a heads-up, the full BOM isn't provided for the Raspberry Pi, so this is just my best guess based on what is available. Looking at the [schematic here](https://datasheets.raspberrypi.com/rpi4/raspberry-pi-4-reduced-schematics.pdf), the LED in in series with a DSS13UTR protection diode, and a 1kOhm resistor. The protection diode from its [datasheet](http://www.smc-diodes.com/propdf/DSS12U%20THRU%20DSS125U%20N1873%20REV.A.pdf) will drop 0.5V when in forward conduction mode (during normal LED operation) so the resistor/LED pair will be dropping about 4.5V.

I measured the pads on the board, and it's clear that it's designed for an 0603 package, side-view diode. Here is a photo below with an 0603 resistor next to it for scale:

[image: Image showing Pi 4 LED]

Looking on Mouser at 0603 package side-view LEDs, there are several options, at a variety of forward voltages, however the most common available is 2V. Looking at a few of these options, it looks like most of them should work just fine for an indicator light use.

Example, SML-A12V8TT86:

Using the nominal forward voltage of 2.2V, that means the current in the LED when on would be (4.5-2.2)/1000 = 2.3mA. Of course, at that current the forward voltage for that model ends up being closer to 1.9V, which gives a current of (4.5-1.9V)/1000 = 2.6mA so that gives an approximate range of where it will end up operating. Looking at the luminous intensity graph, that is within the "on" range, and gives a relative intensity of about 15%, which seems about right for an indicator light. So SML-A12V8TT86 seems like it would work as a replacement.

Example 2: LTST-S270EKT
Using similar analysis on this, we get a relative intensity of around 10%. The graph doesn't have good resolution on the lower end, so this may or may not work.

Hopefully that helps point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Note that you don't have to rework the PCB for this if you don't want to. You can get a LED+resistor assembly which can be soldered to either GND/5V pads some place convenient, or even fitted with jumper cable ends and connected to 5V and GND pins on the GPIO connector:

[image]

The GPIO solution has the benefit of flexibility: if your Pi works, you can just disconnect the LED which has little purpose. If you experience power issues, you can connect the LED and let it tell you whether 5V is present or not. Or you can wire the LED to a USB plug and use it to check the presence of USB power.

Comment: The PWR LED is not connected to 5V, it is actually controlled by kernel software and normally indicates (absence of) "low voltage". It by default adds little of real value.

Comment: @Milliways My bad, I didn't check the schematic at all when answering.

Answer (score 0):

You could replace with practically any LED, but frankly is difficult unless you have the right equipment.

There is also little point. The LED indicates the presence of 5V but is hardly essential and attempting to restore it risks damaging your Pi.

Incidentally "accidentally broke" usually means *ripped a component off* and almost invariably this also means *ripped the board traces off* leaving nothing to solder to. Any such attempt usually causes further damage.

Answer (score 0):

A broken red LED (the "Power LED") need not be a concern. Some people (incl. myself) consider the "Power LED" a nuisance, and prefer that it be disabled. The subject of the "Power LED", and in particular ***how*** to disable it has generated a [huge amount of discussion](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/search.php?keywords=power+led&terms=all&author=&sc=1&sf=titleonly&sr=topics&sk=t&sd=d&st=0&ch=300&t=0&submit=Search) over the years. <sup>[1](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?p=980696#p1550686D), [2](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/1332), [3](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues?q=is%3Aissue+power+led+in%3Atitle)</sup>

Instead of taking on the time, effort & expense of replacing the red LED, you may want to consider this alternative: Disable the "Power LED", and use the green LED ("Activity LED") to indicate both power and activity. It's a simple change; you'll be finished in 2 minutes, and if you don't like it, simply remove it. Here's how:

Open the file `/boot/config.txt` in your editor; e.g.:

```
sudo nano /boot/config.txt
```

Add the following lines near the end of the file:

```
# ACT LED off during disk activity, on all other times
dtparam=act_led_activelow=on
# PWR LED off at all times
dtparam=pwr_led_trigger=none
dtparam=pwr_led_activelow=off
```

After the edits, save the file, close it & reboot. If you want to revert, simply *"comment out"* the 3 `dtparam` lines.